# What is the difference between typescript function default parameter assignment and type checking?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following function

What do I gain or lose with the below

```
getFruits(checkInventory = true){
 if (checkInventory) {}
 ....
}

getFruits(checkInventory: boolean){
 if (checkInventory) {}
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getFruits(checkInventory = true){
 if (checkInventory) {}
 ....
}
```

In this case, you are assigning the default `true` value for the `checkInventory` argument. So you can call the `getFruits` method without passing the `checkInventory` argument: `getFruits()`. This is the same as `getFruits(true)`. If you do not pass any value to this argument, the compiler will use the default value `true` as was defined in the method declaration.

You can still pass another value of any type to the `checkInventory` argument because it was defined implicitly as `any` type, for example `getFruits(123)` or `getFruits("apple")`

But how about the other?

```
getFruits(checkInventory: boolean){
 if (checkInventory) {}
 ....
}
```

You are defining which type for the `checkInventory` argument, not its value. Now you can only pass `boolean` values to the `checkInventory` argument (You can still pass `null` or `undefined` or an object of `any` type to this argument).

You must pass any `boolean` value to the `getFruits` method like `getFruits(true)` or `getFruits(false)`. The compiler will show an error if you use `getFruits()` or `getFruits('apple')`.

But if you still try to pass a string or not provide any value, your application will still run without any compilation errors. TypeScript just provides a static type checking to JavaScript while JavaScript variables can be anything, any type.

Be noticed that errors may occur when your app runs and your passed value can't be read or executed as expected.

Comment: I end up doing `checkInventory: boolean = true`

Comment: @mehany what are you doing with this fumction?

Comment: Nothing special but sometimes I feel like it is more readable to assign a value versus declaring types. It turns out why not both!

Answer (score 0):

The first version you can invoke like so: `getFruits()`. This will be equivalent to `getFruits(false)`.

For the second version, the compiler will exist you explicitly pass in a `checkInventory` value.

Answer (score 0):

For

```
getFruits(checkInventory = true){
 if (checkInventory) {}
 ....
}
```

You are setting the default value for `checkInventory`

So `checkInventory()` is the same as `checkInventory(true)`. Of course, you can override the value by passing in a different value, `checkInventory(true)`.

However, in this case, the argument type isn't defined, which defaults to `any`. So you can call the function with any type of argument. `checkInventory("string")` for example.

For

```
getFruits(checkInventory: boolean){
 if (checkInventory) {}
 ....
}
```

You are defining what the type is for the argument. It needs to be `true` or `false`. This case does not have a default value.

If you try to call this function like `checkInventory("string")`, the compiler will throw an error because it's expecting type `boolean` but got `string` instead.

Comment: So what I really gain is the `the compiler will throw an error because it's expecting type boolean but got string instead`? But I was under the impression that assigning a boolean value will cast the parameter as boolean

Comment: Kindly check my comment, I like to vote up your answer